# One aggregate per transaction, with "one" or "multiple" bounded contexts

Tags: domain-driven-design

Following the Vaughn Vernon recommendation, to achieve a high level of decoupling and single responsibility, just one aggregate should be changed per transaction.

In the chapter 8 of the Red Book Vaughn Vernon demonstrated how two aggregates can "talk" to each other with domain events. In the chapter 13 how different aggregates in two different bounded context can "talk" to each other with notifications.

My question is, why should I deal with these situations differently once both of them happen in different transaction? If is it just one or multiple bounded contexts the possible problems wouldn't be the same?

For example, if the application crashes between two domain events in the same bounded context I'll end up with inconsistency as with two bounded contexts.

It seems that the safest way to deal with two aggregates "talking" to each other asynchronously is to have a transitional status in it, persist the events before send them (to avoid lose events), have idempotent operations when possible and deduplicate the event in the receiving side when it's not possible to execute the operation in an idempotent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two aspects to consider in your question:

1. The DDD aspect: Event types and what you do with them
2. A technical aspect: how to implement it reliably

Regarding the types of Events what I would say is that events that stay within the boundaries of a bounded context (often called Domain Events) normally carry a lot of information. Potentially a big part of the state of the Aggregate. If you use CQRS, they are used to create the Read Model. Events that cross the BC boundaries are sometimes called Integration Events and they should carry as little data as possible (potentially, only global IDs, like CustomerId, OrderId). The reason is that every extra property that you add is extra coupling between the publisher BC and the subscriber BCs, which is what you want to minimize.

I would say that it's this distinction between the types of Events which might lead to have different technical solutions, but I agree with you that it doesn't have to be this way if you find a solution that works well for both cases.

The solution you propose is correct. It looks very similar to the [Outbox feature of NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/), which basically takes care of all this for you.

Another approach that I've used, if your message broker supports it, is what Azure Service Bus calls [Send Via](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions#transfers-and-send-via). With this feature, you can publish events Via your own queue but the send will be committed transactionally with the removal of the incoming message from the queue. This means that if for some reason the message that you are processing is not deleted from the queue successfully (DB update exception, broker unavailable, etc) and therefore it will be retried, you know for sure that the events won't be sent and you can safely publish them again during the retry. This makes making idempotent operations simpler and avoids publishing ghost messages.

Comment: I'm more interested about the potential inconsistency whether in the same bounded context or in different bounded contexts. 

Considering this, I can conclude that I should deal with them in the same way to avoid "real" inconsistency. 

(i) Transitional status in the aggregate; 
(ii) Persist events before send them (to avoid lose events); 
(iii) In the receiving side execute the "domain operation" in an idempotent way when possible. When not possible, deduplicate the event to check if the event had been received before process the domain operation. 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that explanation was my take on why they were presented separately, but I agree that ideally, you treat both types of events the same way. You can certainly do that approach. It's what the Outbox feature I linked does and it works well. The only "inconvenience" with this approach is that you need to make sure that all subscribers implement the deduplication or you'll end up with double processing in some places.

Comment: Francesc Castells, considering this scenario where even internal events go through the bus. I think I'm not wrong to conclude that the bus would be as demanded as a database (maybe even more), right ? I mean, the bus became a critical component. Thanks again!

Comment: If integration events holds very minimal data like just the id's, how to pass the other information required by target? For example, it may be required to send customer details for displaying in an Invoice BC. In those cases do we need to query (http/rpc) using the customerId received through event?

Comment: @Ayyappa you would try to have the data in the right service upfront instead of transferring data from service to service. In the invoice example, all the invoice information belongs to the "Invoicing service". So, the billing name and address will be stored in the invoicing service somewhere during the onboarding flow or checkout. Then when you need to create an invoice when "Ordered Delivered" with OrderId 123, you'll have all the details.